# why pandas series index changed automatically?

Tags: python, pandas

I encountered a strange problem. I have two pandas series

```
Series1
a 0
b 0
c 0
d 0
and Series 2:
b 0
c 2
```

when I tried to add them together by

```
new_series = Series1.add(Series2,fill_value=0)
```

The outcome somehow becomes

```
new_series
a 0
d 0
b 0
c 2
```

Although it does the work for me, the sequence of the index somehow changed. That is so strange, how can I fix the sequence of the new_series? That sequence is really important to me. My original dataset is too long to paste here. Does anyone know what could potential cause this problem? In my real case, the changed index in Series 1 is the last row, and after add, that index somehow goes to the middle of the Series.

Comment: show what is your expected result

Comment: What's your pandas version? my `1.1.0` doesn't change the index's order.